# Invalid regular expression java : unclosed character class

Tags: java, regex, email, email-validation

I'm trying to wite an emailValidator function in java but I have a problem:

```
public static boolean EmailValidator(String mail) {
    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;

    pattern = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z0-9\\]{2,2}(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]{2,2}(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})$");
    matcher = pattern.matcher(mail);

    return matcher.matches();
}
```

**error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 89
^[A-Za-z0-9\]{2,2}(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]{2,2}(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})$
```

Please can someone can tell me what I have to do to fix it, thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have escaped the closing character class character at the beginning:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\\]
```

Remember that after string interpretation this becomes:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\]
```

Since you probably want to include a backslash there try double encoding it:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\\\\]
```

Which becomes the escaped backslash:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\\]
```

Answer (score 0):

it's here `[A-Za-z0-9\\]` it must be `[A-Za-z0-9\\\\]`

Answer (score 0):

In your first section

```
[A-Za-z0-9\\]
```

should be changed to

```
[A-Za-z0-9\\\\]
```